# not all scatter points are shown on plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize points on 3d surface.
For some reason only some points are shown in the plot.
When I start to move the plot around, some points suddenly appear. Is there a way to visualize points on a 3d surface?

This is the result I am getting right now:

[image: plot with only a view points]

And below the code used to generate it:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2)
Z = np.sin(R)

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r', marker='o')

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is probably [this well-known matplotlib problem](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html)